# Are items shared in multiplayer?

Tags: diablo-iii

In multiplayer games, are items visible only to a single person or can everyone see them?

Let's say I'm playing with another guy and a shield drops.  Can he also see, and possibly take, that shield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the in-game tutorial popup will tell you, loot is generated separately per player. You will see your own pool of loot, and other players will see their own loot. You can trade items by picking up the loot and then trading/dropping it, but all of the loot that the boss spews onto the ground is yours to grab.

Comment: Haven't seen any tutorial :) Will take a look once again. Thank you.